# Getting rid of dead ghouls

Tags: fallout-4

This might be a FAQ, but in searching around (and writing the Q) I haven't come across it.  After cleaning out the Sunshine Trading settlement, there are persistent ghoul bodies littering the place.  I tried dragging them to an outhouse and stacking them in there to get them out of the way at least, but after returning from a couple days' exploration they're back where they fell.  I play on X-box, so I don't have a console option.

Comment: Take cannibalism perk and eat them?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't fix those particular corpses.

There exist random corpses that are permeant due to unknown glitches.  There isn't much you can do on the Xbox.

Comment: I have a bandit corpse on the bridge leaving from Sanctuary.  I've since decapitated every limb and it has stayed that way for over 400 hrs.  I've even thrown it into the water but it has always teleported back to the bridge.

Comment: same problem.  Even dropped a nuke on it and it flew everywhere.  Was back to new after a couple of hours.  Well as new as a naked dead body could ever get.